# UICollectionView Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _updateWithItems:tentativelyForReordering:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

iOS8.4. On device not simulator.

I'm getting this carsh error;

`Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _updateWithItems:tentativelyForReordering:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44.2/UICollectionView.m:4563`

When I call

```
NSArray* array_indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
```

have tried putting the above inside
`[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{`
with no luck.

Is there anyone else who has experienced this or knows why it's happening?

Comment: Did you resolve this somehow?

Comment: I didn't. I ended-up fundementally changing the whole thing completely, and never needing to make this call. I never got to the bottom of why this was happening for the above call though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this rdar: http://www.openradar.me/26280932 which says:

> Calling insertItemsAtIndexPaths: on UICollectionView after viewDidLoad but before viewDidAppear: will cause an assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:]. Calling reloadData in the same scenario doesn't generate the assertion.

So you could check if you are doing your call before `viewDidAppear` and adjust/wait before view did appear.